# Insert elements (strings) within existing XML tags using a RegEX?

Tags: xml, regex, tags, sed, markup

Insert attributes (strings) within existing tags.

I need to insert the number found within `<pagenum><pagenum/>` into the `id=`attribute so in this example.

I start with:

`<pagenum page="normal" id="page">1<pagenum/>`

and I need to replace it with:

`<pagenum page="normal" id="page1">1<pagenum/>`

The string in there could be any alphanumeric value.

What would this regex look like?
Something like this?

`/s/<pagenum page="normal" id="page">1<pagenum//>/<pagenum page="normal" id="page"{Value}>1\<pagenum/>`

I`m too rusty on my backreferencing...

Comment: Indeed, I missed a few quotes... They're in there now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I changed the regex delimiter from / to ! to have a little less confusion)
- to escape characters you use a backslash not a forward slash

Try:

```
s!(<pagenum page="normal" id=")([a-z0-9_-]+)(">)([0-9]+)(<pagenum/>)!\1\2\4\3\4\5!i
```

e.g.:

```
echo '<pagenum page="normal" id="page">1<pagenum/>' | \
sed -r 's!(<pagenum page="normal" id=")([a-z0-9_-]+)(">)([0-9]+)(<pagenum/>)!\1\2\4\3\4\5!i'
```

Note - isn't a closing tag usually `</pagenum>` as opposed to `<pagenum/>`?

Comment: It should in fact read `echo '<pagenum page="normal" id="page">1</pagenum>' | \
sed -E 's!(<pagenum page="normal" id=")([a-z0-9_-]+)(">)([0-9]+)(</pagenum>)!\1\2\4\3\4\5!g'` The expression is extended and needs to be global. I've fixed my slash nightmare. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah you're on Mac (BSD sed has `-E`, GNU sed has `-r`).

Comment: Indeed. I use Linux enough its good to know the difference. I'm guessing I could always install the GNU sed on the Mac Right?